# Derivative of Kummer's confluent hypergeometric with respect to parameter?

Tags: hypergeometric-function

[Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function) is:

$$M(a,b;z)= {_1}F_1(a,b;z)$$

There is an [easy recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Contiguous_relations) for the derivative of $M$ with respect to $z$. I am interested in the derivative with respect to the parameters $a,b$. Are there any known relations involving

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial a}, \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{\partial M}{\partial b}?$$

Comment: This looks to do it:  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234904587_Derivatives_of_any_order_of_the_confluent_hypergeometric_function_1F1abz_with_respect_to_the_parameter_a_or_b

Comment: For the derivative of ${_1F_1}\left(-\nu; 1; x\right)$ with respect to $\nu,$ see question [Proving an identity involving the derivative of the Laguerre polynomials with respect to n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179769/proving-an-identity-involving-the-derivative-of-the-laguerre-polynomials-with-re)